# How to stop my Tkinter window from freezing?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

Below is the main function I use in order to run two files of python but once I click on the buttuon my window freezes.Please tell me a way to perform multi threaading so that I can click both the buttons at once.

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

from tkinter import *

from tkinter.ttk import *

from tkinter import messagebox

import threading

import Test1

import Test2

# In[ ]:



def Load1():



    Test1.func()

    messagebox.showinfo( "Successful","Reconcilation Complete")



def Load2():

    Test2.func()

    try:

        messagebox.showinfo( "Successful","Reconcilation Complete")

    except Exception as inst:

        messagebox.showinfo( "Unsuccessful",inst)

root = Tk()



root.geometry('375x100')

root.title("Reco")



root.configure(background="LightBlue2")

style = Style()

style.configure('TButton', background = 'SeaGreen2', font =

               ('calibri', 20, 'bold'))



btn1 = Button(root, text = 'Tier Recon', command =threading.Thread(target=Load1).start )

btn1.grid(row = 1, column = 3, pady = 10, padx = 100)



btn2 = Button(root, text = 'View Recon', command =threading.Thread(target=Load2).start)

btn2.grid(row = 2, column = 3, pady = 10, padx = 100)



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: In your other scripts you call tk.Tk again?

Comment: Please fix the formatting of the posted code.

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed your `Test1` and `Test2` functions are somewhat infinite so I have created this as the format for my `Test1.py` and `Test2.py`:

```
# Test1.py / Test2.py
import tkinter as tk
def func():
    while True:
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.mainloop()
```

Now with your code I would thoroughly recommend moving away from your current format and moving to [Object Oriented Programming](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A0gaXfM1UN0) as it will save you many headaches in the future!

This here is the code I have written to make it work:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import Test1
import Test2

class reco_win:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry('375x100')
        self.master.configure(background="LightBlue2")
        style = ttk.Style()
        style.configure('TButton', background = 'SeaGreen2', font =
                ('calibri', 20, 'bold'))

        btn1 = ttk.Button(self.master, text = 'Tier Recon', command = lambda: self.master.after(1, self.load1))

        btn1.grid(row = 1, column = 3, pady = 10, padx = 100)

        btn2 = ttk.Button(self.master, text = 'View Recon', command =lambda: self.master.after(1, self.load1))

        btn2.grid(row = 2, column = 3, pady = 10, padx = 100)

    def load1(self):
        Test1.func()

    def load2(self):
        Test2.func()

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    reco_win(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

#### The important bit in this code:

```py
self.master.after(1, self.load1)
```

What this line of code does is after 1 millisecond it will asynchronously start a new thread and execute the function `Test1.func()`.

This means that you don't have to worry about the issues with managing the multithreading module in python and you can instead work on writing more code!

Hope this helps,

James

P.S.

If you are using a `tk.Tk()` window in your `Test1/Test2.py` you could instead use a `tk.TopLevel` window which would allow you to rewrite this code to read like so:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import Test1
import Test2

class reco_win:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry('375x100')
        self.master.configure(background="LightBlue2")
        style = ttk.Style()
        style.configure('TButton', background = 'SeaGreen2', font =
                ('calibri', 20, 'bold'))

        btn1 = ttk.Button(self.master, text = 'Tier Recon', command = self.load1)

        btn1.grid(row = 1, column = 3, pady = 10, padx = 100)

        btn2 = ttk.Button(self.master, text = 'View Recon', command =self.load2)

        btn2.grid(row = 2, column = 3, pady = 10, padx = 100)

    def load1(self):
        top = tk.Toplevel()
        tk.Label(top, text="Hello").grid(row=0, column=0)

    def load2(self):
        top2 = tk.Toplevel()
        tk.Label(top2, text="Hello 2").grid(row=0, column=0)

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    reco_win(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```